# Why do London Underground Bakerloo line trains have a driver's carriage in the middle of the train?

Tags: public-transport, tfl

I need to know! Surely they're not half the length of all other lines because the platforms are full length...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel as defined in the [help]

Comment: It is **not** off-topic: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4774/are-questions-on-cultural-stereotypes-and-behaviour-unrelated-to-travel-on-top (and many more [Are questions about posts on meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=are+questions+about+is%3Aq)), so certainly not anything about a mode of transport in the country.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason for many Bakerloo line trains having an extra driving cab car in the train somewhere is because the current carriages/trains were not originally purchased for that line.  The current stock is (refurbished) 1972 train sets which were Northern Line stock.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Underground_1972_Stock

Northern line trains were a carriage shorter

[This page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Underground_rolling_stock) gives a longer overview of the historical rolling stock of the system.